# UILabel shows incorrect text in last line when text contains a line break and label has limited numberOfLines and lineBreakMode .byTruncatingTail

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel, line-breaks

If you run the code snippet below, it will show incorrect text in the last line that has the ... ellipsis, as show in this image:

[image]

Once you change the lineBreakMode to `byWordWrapping`, or set the `numberOfLines` to 0, then the text is displayed correctly. Also, if you remove the line break `/n` from the text, then the text is displayed correctly.

So my question is: How can I use a /n line break in the text in a UILabel with a limited numberOfLines and lineBreakMode .byTruncatingTail without showing incorrect text on the last line?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let text = "A line break challenge \nInvestigating a bug where the text in the last line is incorrect when numberOfLines is limited to for example 3. Very strange indeed. Peculiar. What to do about this? What am I missing?"
        
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail //.byWordWrapping works, but not what I want.

        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
        ])
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.attributedText = attributedString
        label.numberOfLines = 3 //0 works, but is not what I want.

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
        label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... just confirming what you're seeing. It appears to be a bug. `iOS 15.4` on simulator and device: text is displayed incorrectly. `iOS 15.2` simulator, no problem. I also have a phone still running `iOS 15.1` - also no problem. Worth reporting to Apple.

Comment: Done! FB10003875

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue right now. Thanks for bringing it up!