# Specifying NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail causes issues when displaying NSAttributedString in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel, nsattributedstring

In my app, I fetch some HTML strings from the Wordpress REST API of a website. I use the following extension to convert the HTML to an NSAttributedString that I can display in my UILabel:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    
    convenience init(htmlString html: String, font: UIFont? = nil, useDocumentFontSize: Bool = false) throws {
        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] = [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]

        let data = html.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        guard (data != nil), let fontFamily = font?.familyName, let attr = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else {
            try self.init(data: data ?? Data(html.utf8), options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
            return
        }

        let fontSize: CGFloat? = useDocumentFontSize ? nil : font!.pointSize
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attr.length)
        attr.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: range, options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { attrib, range, _ in
            if let htmlFont = attrib as? UIFont {
                let traits = htmlFont.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
                var descrip = htmlFont.fontDescriptor.withFamily(fontFamily)

                if (traits.rawValue & UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits.traitBold.rawValue) != 0 {
                    descrip = descrip.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)!
                }

                if (traits.rawValue & UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits.traitItalic.rawValue) != 0 {
                    descrip = descrip.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic)!
                }

                attr.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(descriptor: descrip, size: fontSize ?? htmlFont.pointSize), range: range)
                attr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.label, range: range)
            }
        }

        self.init(attributedString: attr)
    }

}
```

The UILabel is defined as follows:

```
let myLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
        return label
}()
```

I use the following code to display the NSAttributedString in the UILabel:

```
let contentAttributed = try? NSAttributedString(htmlString: html, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular))
myLabel.attributedText = contentAttributed
myLabel.numberOfLines = 3
```

With this, everything works as expected, as shown in two examples below:

[Example 1 (everything ok)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8RQx.png)

[Example 2 (everything ok)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVVi6.png)

I would really like the UILabels to be completely filled and with ellipsis at the end (truncated lines). If I add `myLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail` into my code, there are weird issues, as shown in the same examples below. The weird thing is that some of the UILabels still work absolutely fine (example 2), while others show the weird issues (example 1).

[Example 1 (issues)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBXbP.png)

[Example 2 (still everything ok)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzfwT.png)

If anyone knows where in this rather complicated issue I should start digging, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Some examples of HTML strings that produce the issue:

```
\n<p>Liebe Damen &amp; Herren</p>\n\n\n\n<p>Erneut trifft es uns und wir müssen die Sammlung vom Samstag <strong>bis auf Weiteres verschieben!</strong>
```

```
\n<p>\n\nLiebe Kollegen</p>\n\n\n\n<p>Am 28. August führen wir (endlich) wieder die Papiersammlung in der Gemeinde durch. Dabei sind wir auf möglichst viele Helfer:innen angewiesen.</p>
```

```
\n<p>​Liebe Kollegen</p>\n\n\n\n<p>Nur ungerne stören wir eure Sommerferien mit einer unerfreulichen Nachricht: <strong>Das Katre 2021 vom 4. und 5. September wurde leider abgesagt!</strong></p>
```

The following HTML strings do not produce the issue:

```
\n<p>Kürzlich hat der Bundesrat über die in Etappen stattfindende Lockerung der Massnahmen zum Schutz vor dem Coronavirus informiert. Leider haben die ersten Lockerungen des Bundes noch keinen Einfluss auf uns.</p>
```

```
<p>Liebe Eltern und Kollegen</p>\n<p>Unser Jahresprogramm für 2019 ist nun fertig und online. Ihr findet es unter Medien -&gt; Downloads oder direkt hier:</p>\n<p><a href=\"https: //somelink.com\">Jahresprogramm_2019</a></p>
```

The App is run on the iPhone 13 Pro Simulator in portrait orientation. The UILabel is part of a custom UITableViewCell. The UITableView is aligned to the safe area on the left and right (constant 0). The UILabel is aligned to the contentView.leadingAnchor and contentView.trailingAnchor with a constant of 30 and -30, respectively.

Comment: Quick test, cannot reproduce what you're seeing. Edit your question and include the HTML string(s) you are using, and the width of your label.

Comment: I have added some HTML strings and the details about the UILabel.

Comment: Hmmm... I was able to reproduce the problem with your HTML strings. I've seen this once before (here on Stack Overflow), but I can't remember if we resolved it or determined it's a bug. I will try to find it.

Comment: If you're interested in a work-around, I posted one at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this answer, not because it is a solution but because I think it is worth discussion...

---

**Edit**

<s>Personally, I would say Attributed Text and `.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail` is rather buggy.</s>

This does not appear to be related to **Attributed Text**, but rather to the presence of a newline character.

For example, if the label is set to `.numberOfLines = 3` and we use this text:

```
myLabel.text = "Let's test this:\nPlenty of text to wrap onto more than three lines. Note this is plain text, not attributed text. It may or may not exhibit the same problems."
```

we will see the same corrupted text wrapping occur.

Also note: this does **NOT** happen on iOS prior to `15.4`!

**/Edit**

---

In all the following examples, the same attributed string is used for pairs of rows, but only the cyan labels have `myLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail`.

---

First note:

If we set `myLabel.numberOfLines = 0`, we get this output:

[image]

Which doesn't make much sense... Apparently, a newline character gets factored in at the end of the attributed string -- but even so, we get ***almost, but not*** enough space for TWO additional lines (I'm guessing it's a newline and a paragraph vertical space?):

[image]

---

Second note:

If we ***DO NOT*** have enough text to exceed the bounds of the label (again, we're setting `myLabel.numberOfLines = 3` here), we get another oddity. This is when I rotate the device:

[image]

Even though the text is NOT truncated, we get the `...` -- because UIKit is trying to add 1.5 additional blank lines at the end of the string.

---

Third note:

As I mentioned in a comment, I **know** we came across this once before here on SO -- unfortunately, I can't remember if we resolved it or (probably) not.

---

**To reproduce with Plain Text**

```
class WrapBugVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 4
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 315.0),
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
        ])

        var vInfo: UILabel
        
        let testStr1: String = "Let's test this (no newline character): Plenty of text to wrap onto more than three lines. Note this is plain text, not attributed text."
        let testStr2: String = "Let's test this:\nPlenty of text to wrap onto more than three lines. Note this is plain text, not attributed text."

        vInfo = UILabel()
        vInfo.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        vInfo.text = "NO newline, .byWordWrapping"
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(vInfo)
        
        let v1 = UILabel()
        v1.numberOfLines = 3
        v1.text = testStr1
        v1.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v1.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v1)
        
        vInfo = UILabel()
        vInfo.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        vInfo.text = "NO newline, .byTruncatingTail"
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(vInfo)
        
        let v2 = UILabel()
        v2.numberOfLines = 3
        v2.text = testStr1
        v2.backgroundColor = .cyan
        v2.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v2)
        
        vInfo = UILabel()
        vInfo.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        vInfo.text = "WITH newline, .byWordWrapping"
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(vInfo)
        
        let v3 = UILabel()
        v3.numberOfLines = 3
        v3.text = testStr2
        v3.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v3.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v3)

        vInfo = UILabel()
        vInfo.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        vInfo.text = "WITH newline, .byTruncatingTail"
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(vInfo)
        
        let v4 = UILabel()
        v4.numberOfLines = 3
        v4.text = testStr2
        v4.backgroundColor = .cyan
        v4.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v4)

        [v1, v2, v3, v4].forEach { v in
            stackView.setCustomSpacing(16.0, after: v)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Workaround**

You may want to try this as a workaround...

```
class TextViewLabel: UITextView {
    
    public var numberOfLines: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
        }
    }
    public var lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail {
        didSet {
            textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        isScrollEnabled = false
        isEditable = false
        isSelectable = false
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    }
    
}
```

Using `TextViewLabel` in place of `UILabel` will avoid the bug:

[image]

---

**Edit 2**

As of `iOS 16.2` there are still inconsistencies with word-wrapping and tail-truncation between `UILabel` and `UITextView`.

Here is some code to see them side-by-side:

```
// a replacement for UILabel
class TextViewLabel: UITextView {
    
    public var numberOfLines: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
        }
    }
    public var lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail {
        didSet {
            textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        isScrollEnabled = false
        isEditable = false
        isSelectable = false
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    }
    
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let labelStackView = UIStackView()
    let textViewStackView = UIStackView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        
        let hStack = UIStackView()
        hStack.axis = .horizontal
        hStack.spacing = 8
        hStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        hStack.alignment = .top
        
        [labelStackView, textViewStackView].forEach { v in
            v.axis = .vertical
            v.spacing = 4
            hStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        hStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(hStack)

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            hStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            hStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            hStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            hStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            hStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.widthAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
        ])
        
        let infoFont: UIFont = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 10.0)
        let testFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
        
        var testStr: String = "This is some example text to test truncation consistency. At the end of this line, is a pair of newline chars:\n\nA HEADLINE\n\nThe headline was also followed by a pair of newline chars."

        for i in 3...10 {
            
            let infoLabel = UILabel()
            infoLabel.font = infoFont
            infoLabel.text = "UILabel - numLines: \(i)"
            labelStackView.addArrangedSubview(infoLabel)
            
            let v = UILabel()
            v.font = testFont
            v.numberOfLines = i
            v.text = testStr
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            v.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
            labelStackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
            
            labelStackView.setCustomSpacing(16.0, after: v)
            
        }
        
        for i in 3...10 {
            
            let infoLabel = UILabel()
            infoLabel.font = infoFont
            infoLabel.text = "TextViewLabel - numLines: \(i)"
            textViewStackView.addArrangedSubview(infoLabel)
            
            let v = TextViewLabel()
            v.font = testFont
            v.numberOfLines = i
            v.text = testStr
            v.backgroundColor = .cyan
            v.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
            textViewStackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
            
            textViewStackView.setCustomSpacing(16.0, after: v)
            
        }
        
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }
    
}
```

Differences also exist from one iOS version to another - for example:

[image]

Comment: I'm back to investigating issues with new lines and truncation in UILabel and UITextView. There was a bug in iOS 15.2 that got resolved by Apple in later releases on UILabel not showing the last line correctly when truncating (https://stackoverflow.com/q/72015424/2743633). Now I am seeing on iOS 16.x that truncation is not happening when there are double new line characters. I tried the workaround UITextView but it fails when there are multiple double new lines in the text.

Comment: UITextView fails to show the three dots when numberOfLines = 6 and text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\n\nLOREM IPSUM\n\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Comment: @Samuël - yeah... UIKit changes and bugs are so fun! See my **Edit 2** above.

Comment: bottom line, it's buggy and you can't count on truncation to work whatever approach you take, either UILabel or UITextView. For my users it is important it always works, so I'm going with a fixed number of characters and if more, than adding truncation ellipsis myself instead of leaving that to UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the strings that work only have one paragraph of text, whereas the ones that do not have multiple. Apple's documentation implies that `lineBreakMode` applies to the label's whole `attributedText`, as long as it's set *after* the `attributedText` is assigned a value. That doesn't explain this behavior though, and the fact that parts of the string are being repeated makes me think this is a bug on how multi-paragraph NSAttributedStrings interact with a label's `lineBreakMode`.

`NSMutableParagraphStyle` has a property called `lineBreakMode`, which will allow you to set the line break mode for each paragraph individually. That might give you a few different options for workarounds.

Alternatively - setting the `numberOfLines` to 0 also fixes the problem for me, though it's not ideal since it might require you to set a max height for the label, which could worsen the user experience with dynamic font sizes.

Viel Glück!

Comment: I have found that the number of paragraphs doesn't matter. Just look at the second example of the strings that don't show the issue. I might have to try some workarounds, thanks for the answer.