# Set a special string to the UILabel, but the part of string is duplicated and be strange

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, uilabel

My user report a bug that the texts is strange and he did not taped that.
So I get the texts and create a simple project, only create a label and set the texts to it.
The texts is here:

`【Does this sound natural?】\n \"Who's that?\" \"That's Tom when he was a kid.\" \"Do you have a same picture of Mary?`

If I do not limit the number of label's line, there is no issue, but when set the number of line to 3, the text `"That's Tom when` occurred two times! And texts is became strange.

[image]

All code is here

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var label: UILabel = {
       let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 220, height: 100))
        label.numberOfLines = 3
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        return label
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        self.label.text = "【Does this sound natural?】\n \"Who's that?\" \"That's Tom when he was a kid.\" \"Do you have a same picture of Mary?"
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems an iOS bug.  What happens when you set the `label.text` in `viewWillAppear()` instead?

Comment: @meaning-matters Move the text's setting to `viewWillAppear` didn't work,  if delete the `\n` in text, the issue would be gone but I don't know the reason or the relationship to the issues.

Comment: @ImWH - this is definitely an easily reproducible bug in 15.5 ... I don't have the next beta installed anywhere, so don't know if it's been fixed.

Comment: See also the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73419016/6257435

Answer (score 4):

According to the discussion [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705600)  it is a bug occurring after iOS 15.4.

There is a workaround mentioned in the above thread.

I also faced the same issue and I changed the `UILabel` to a `UITextView` with the two options

```
label.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 3
label.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

Check if either of workarounds will work in your case.