# Duplication of text when Truncate Tail selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am seeing text duplication in my table cells. My cell allows for 4 lines of text to be displayed and if there is more it truncates the tail.

The issue occurs when there is more than 3 lines of text without any line breaks.

I currently have "Truncate Tail" selected in Xcode. If I change it to "Word Wrap" then there is no text duplication, however, I want the Elipsis (...) to be shown as well as have word wrap.

Here is the only snippet of code in connection with the subtitle cell. Below I attached a couple pics. 1) The cells with Word Wrap selected. 2) The cells with Truncate Tail selected. 3) The source of the text in the cell.

```
if adjustedNotes == "" {
        cell.subtitleLabel.text = "\(dateString)\n"
    } else if adjustedNotes == "add notes" {
        cell.subtitleLabel.text = "\(dateString)\n"
    } else {
        cell.subtitleLabel.text = "\(dateString)\n\(adjustedNotes)"
    }
```

[image: Cell with Word Wrap selected]

[image: Cell with Truncate Tail selected]

[image: Full text that is in the cell]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415503/set-a-special-string-to-the-uilabel-but-the-part-of-string-is-duplicated-and-be ?

Comment: Thanks for the link! I tried a number of searches to find someone discussing this issue, but struck out.

Since it is apparently just a bug, I can use simple Word Wrap without the ellipsis until the next update and hopefully they fix it.

Comment: See also the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73419016/6257435 ... it includes a workaround.